# When the normalizer of a subgroup is itself?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $H \leq G$. When do we have the equality that $N_G (H)=H ?$

Comment: There is a cute lemma about $p$-groups: If $|G|=p^n$ for some prime $p$ (i.e. $G$ is a finite "$p$-group"), then for any $H\lneq G$ it is $N_G(H)\neq H$. This gives a (weak) neccessary condition for your question (i.e. $|G|$ may not be a prime power). It is certainly not sufficient though.

Comment: @Simon We can extend this property to any nilpotent group $G$. If $H<G$, then $H<N_G(H)$. All $p$-groups are nilpotent.